# Create function to make groups in data.table based on predicted outcome and compute mean difference confidence intervals

Tags: r, function, statistics, data.table, confidence-interval

Hi I have the following sample of a data.table

```
n = 100000

DT = data.table(dummy = rbinom(n, 1, 0.4), 
                         observed = 50 + sample.int(52, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                         predicted = sample.int(102, size = n, replace = TRUE))

head(DT)
```

I need to create a function that basically creates groups from 1 to 20 (using say cut.number in ggplot) that creates 20 ascending groups based on predicted outcomes.

For each group, I need to compute the difference in average observed outcomes for observations with dummy == 0 and dummy == 1.

For e.g. group 1 will be the lowest 5% of the data.table based on predicted spend. For this group, I need to have a column that computes the difference in means of the observed column for dummy == 0 and dummy == 1.

I then need to create 2 columns with lower and upper confidence intervals (using a difference of means standard errors).

Currently, here's the code I have for the function

```
#Create function
Table <- function(observed1, observed0, predicted, N_groups = 20) { 
  DT1 = data.table(observed0 = observed0, observed1 = observed1, predicted = predicted) 
  DT1[, score_group := as.integer(cut_number(predicted, n = N_groups))]
  DT2 = DT1[, .(predicted = mean(predicted),
                   X = mean(observed1),
                   Y = mean(observed0),
                   N = .N,
                   std_error = sqrt((var(observed1)/nrow(observed1))+(var(observed0)/nrow(observed0)))),
               keyby = score_group]

  #Standard error of difference in means
  DT2[, `:=`(lower_CI = X - Y + qt(0.025, df = nrow(observed1)-1 + nrow(observed0)-1)*std_error,
                 upper_CI = X - Y + qt(0.975, df = nrow(observed1)-1 + nrow(observed0)-1)*std_error), 
          keyby = score_group]
  return(DT2)
}
```

This is obviously wrong since I get NAs on my standard error and CI computation and it's not picking up the number of rows of the dummy -- 1 and dummy == 0 correctly. It's picking up the total number of rows for both (n/20) which is not what it's supposed to do.

This is how I'm currently using the function

```
Table(DT[dummy == 1, observed], 
  DT[dummy == 0, observed], 
  DT$predicted, 
  N_groups)
```

I do need a function and a data.table solution. Please help!

```
score_group  predicted        X        Y      N    std_error lower_CI upper_CI
 1:           1   3.552568 76.40180 76.71253 5764        NA       NA       NA
 2:           2   9.020897 76.59119 76.44898 4929        NA       NA       NA
 3:           3  13.990248 76.50569 76.72836 4922        NA       NA       NA
 4:           4  19.012041 76.71393 76.13349 4817        NA       NA       NA
 5:           5  23.992017 76.63382 76.98256 4760        NA       NA       NA
 6:           6  29.017115 76.27058 76.51243 4908        NA       NA       NA
 7:           7  34.005055 76.45592 76.46684 4946        NA       NA       NA
 8:           8  38.984464 76.25172 76.58368 5085        NA       NA       NA
 9:           9  44.000000 76.13215 76.49909 4949        NA       NA       NA
10:          10  49.510715 76.65609 76.12189 5833        NA       NA       NA
11:          11  55.008938 76.47674 76.41519 4923        NA       NA       NA
12:          12  59.986612 76.32976 76.14253 4855        NA       NA       NA
13:          13  64.958274 76.35325 76.84586 4937        NA       NA       NA
14:          14  70.013035 76.75316 76.79226 4833        NA       NA       NA
15:          15  75.004029 76.62067 76.83602 4964        NA       NA       NA
16:          16  79.960352 76.62068 76.33824 4893        NA       NA       NA
17:          17  85.026246 76.04252 76.35788 4915        NA       NA       NA
18:          18  90.021586 76.78144 76.61000 4818        NA       NA       NA
19:          19  94.974199 76.44890 76.46483 4961        NA       NA       NA
20:          20 100.023657 76.42763 76.89435 4988        NA       NA       NA
Warning messages:
1: In data.table(observed0 = observed0, observed1 = observed1, predicted = predicted) :
  Item 1 is of size 59991 but maximum size is 100000 (recycled leaving remainder of 40009 items)
2: In data.table(observed0 = observed0, observed1 = observed1, predicted = predicted) :
  Item 2 is of size 40009 but maximum size is 100000 (recycled leaving remainder of 19982 items)
```

Comment: In the standard error part of your function, you're using `nrow` on vectors.  You should use `length` instead.

Comment: So it solves the NA problem when I run it, but I still get the following warning message. Any thoughts on why?:

1: In data.table(observed0 = observed0, observed1 = observed1, predicted = predicted) :
  Item 1 is of size 60010 but maximum size is 100000 (recycled leaving remainder of 39990 items)
2: In data.table(observed0 = observed0, observed1 = observed1, predicted = predicted) :
  Item 2 is of size 39990 but maximum size is 100000 (recycled leaving remainder of 20020 items)

Comment: The number of rows in `DT` where `dummy == 1` is not equal to the number where `dummy == 0`.  This means you're passing vectors of different lengths to the `data.table` function, which it doesn't like.  You're probably better off computing the statistics with `DT[, <compute stats>, by = dummy]` and working with that output.